# State use as props in component, state change will not re-render the component

Tags: reactjs, components, state

React will re-render if the state is changed. Then why the following situation cannot be re-render?

Base on the program behavior, I found that

1. when state change, if the state is use directly in the component, it will be re-rendered.
2. when state change, if the state is use as props in child component, it will not be re-rendered.
3. how can I directly re-render that child component?

The following program is come from my code with some modification.
Update:
[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0wff7)
This is the code i created in sandbox, I have try to simulate my real situation

```
function List(props) {

    const [fullListValue, setFullListValue] = useState([]); //store data which get from server
    const [dropDrowList, setDropDrowList] = useState([]); //store data column value (e.g. data contain "fruit" column, this state will store "apple", "berry", "banana" etc.)

    const setAllList = (data) => {
        setFullListValue(data);
    };
    useEffect ( ()=> {
      //axios call server, use setAllList(data) to save state
    ,[]}

    //when fullListValue is updated, 
    useEffect(() => {
        const dropDrowListCopy = [{ ['label']: 'ALL', ['value']: 'ALL' }];
        //push all "fruit" data in dropDrowListCopy without duplicate
        console.log(dropDrowListCopy); //this will show all dropdown I want, i.e. "ALL","apple", "berry", "banana"
        setDropDrowList(dropDrowListCopy); //set to dropDrowList, and I expect this step will re-render the SelectionList component, however, it do not
    }, [fullListValue]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {dropDrowList.length <= 1 ? (
                    'loading'  //I add this to re-render the component, but I think this is not a good way to re-render the component
                ) : ( 
                    <SelectionList
                        itemList={dropDrowList}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Can you share `SectionList` code? And perhaps a more accurate example of how you are updating state.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/0wff7  
This is the code i created in sandbox, I have try to simulate my real situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

In `SecitonList`, you are storing passed props into state but not updating state when props change, leaving you with stale state. It's actually a React anti-pattern to store props in local component state for this reason.

## Solution

Update state when props change.

```
function SelectionList(props) {
  const [listItem, setListItem] = useState(
    props.itemList ? props.itemList : []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setListItem(props.itemList);
  },
  [props.itemList]);

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Select
        renderValue={
          props.multiple ? (selected) => fieldDisplay(selected) : null
        }
        input={<Input />}
      >
        {listItem.map((item) => (
          <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item}>
            {props.multiple ? (
              <Checkbox checked={selectedValue.indexOf(item) > -1} />
            ) : null}
            <ListItemText primary={item.label} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

## Solution - directly consume props

```
function SelectionList(props) {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Select
        renderValue={
          props.multiple ? (selected) => fieldDisplay(selected) : null
        }
        input={<Input />}
      >
        {props.itemList.map((item) => (
          <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item}>
            {props.multiple ? (
              <Checkbox checked={selectedValue.indexOf(item) > -1} />
            ) : null}
            <ListItemText primary={item.label} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank! In other word, I only update the state in parent component, but in child, the state (which is passed from parent) is not updated. Therefore, the bug come out. am my understand correct?

Comment: @0o0SkY0o0 More or less, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this condition:

```
dropDrowList.length <= 1
```

You are only assigning 1 object to the dropDrowList so it will not render the SelectionList.

Changing to:

```
dropDrowList.length < 1
```

Should enable SelectionList to render.

Comment: dropDrowList.length <= 1 is because the dropDrowList contain at least "ALL", therefore, the dropDrowList need to have 2 or more. 0 or 1 item in dropDrowList is not allowed.

Comment: @0o0SkY0o0 Then add another item to it in your useEffect() (or somewhere else) otherwise it will never render due to that condition.

Comment: Suggestion: assign the array to have 2 values in useEfect: const dropDrowList = [{label: ‘ALL’, value: ‘ALL’},{label: ‘Test’, value:’Test’}]; This will allow SelectionList to render.